# Horizontal align images in a container

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am trying to have 3 images aligned in one block. They have to stay in the same sized container and fit horizontally.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="container">
   <img src="http://images2.webydo.com/31/313624/3958/21b785db-14ea-42f7-af0d-7e7a8d8019d9.jpg" />
   <img src="http://images2.webydo.com/31/313624/3958/9657ddfd-81e8-4154-bc61-bbe30e4a8740.jpg" />
   <img src="http://images2.webydo.com/31/313624/3958/909af36d-b941-4a20-9441-20505c035da3.jpg"/>
</div>


.container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
.container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbmkr/) what you mean?

Comment: looks like each image has a width of 100% - that does not look right...specially if the container is only 300px wide... (each image would take the full width of the container)

Comment: The question is not clear, @user3412999 – could you please clarify?

Comment: Thank you eveyrone. Fixing the % of width really helped. and adding the right code for padding. However, I could only get it to equally spread out and either the heights of all 3 images didn't match or the image is out of proportion. Any quick fixes before I go re-crop all my images? The CSS now: .container {
    width: auto;
    height: 200px;
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
.container img {
    width: 30%;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm...I don't think you can have all three images in a horizontal line if you give them all a `width:100%`. That property would cause each image to take the full width of the container, meaning each image would be pushed to the next line.

You'll have to give the images a smaller width to fit them all on one line. 100% / 3 = 33.3% (rounded), so use that instead. Here's some modified CSS for `.container img` that seems to work:

```
.container img {
    width: 33.3%;
    height: auto;
    padding:5px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Note that in addition to changing the images' widths, I also changed the `margin` to `padding`, and made use of the `box-sizing` attribute (read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)). This lets you keep that same spacing of 5px around images, without bumping any images onto a second line.

Also, the HTML needs to be altered slightly. In this case, we're taking advantage of the `<img>` element's default `display:inline-block` to have them all display on the same line. However, any whitespace in between this kind of element will result in a space between the images, so that needs to be eliminated:

```
<div class="container">
   <img src="http://images2.webydo.com/31/313624/3958/21b785db-14ea-42f7-af0d-7e7a8d8019d9.jpg" /><img src="http://images2.webydo.com/31/313624/3958/9657ddfd-81e8-4154-bc61-bbe30e4a8740.jpg" /><img src="http://images2.webydo.com/31/313624/3958/909af36d-b941-4a20-9441-20505c035da3.jpg"/>
</div>
```

If you don't understand what I mean by that, try formatting each `<img>` element onto its own line in the HTML, and see how that affects their positioning.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7qB4G/1/) so you can see what this achieves. Let me know if you have any questions, and I'll be happy to help further!

EDIT: Alternatively, if you really want to keep the whitespace between your `<img>` elements in your HTML, you could compensate for the unwanted extra space with a negative margin. Just add `margin-right:-4px;` to your styles for `.container img`. Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7qB4G/2/) to show what this results in.

Comment: Thank you Serlite! Really did help but now the height of my images don't match or the images are out of proportion.

Comment: Great! Glad it helped out. Unfortunately, that is a side effect of having all the images in a horizontal line within a container of a static width. Unless they all have the same aspect ratio, the images will appear at different heights using this method. (I don't see a good pure CSS way of doing that within those parameters.)

Comment: I'm also trying to get it to fade to 50% when hovered over in jquery. When it's faded. the title of the painting to show up. This is what I have so far: $(document).ready(function(){
$('.container').hover(function(){
$(this).fadeTo(0.5,'fast');
});
});

Comment: Your parameters for fadeTo() are reversed. Here, applied to the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7qB4G/3/

Comment: Also, you can attach two callbacks to the hover() function, for when the cursor enters and leaves the area. Here's another JSFiddle, where the container fades in and out, and a title appears: http://jsfiddle.net/7qB4G/4/

Comment: This jQuery seems to fade out all 3 images though

Comment: Oh, I see. You wanted only each image to fade individually? Then you'd want to use the ".container img" selector, rather than just ".container". Here's a basic demonstration of how you could do this using a data attribute on each image. You can take it further as you see fit by repositioning the title to appear over the current image if you want. http://jsfiddle.net/7qB4G/5/

Comment: Or better yet, here. This should be exactly what you need, though you'll need to tweak it. Positions the title over each `<img>`. Make sure you read the code and understand how it works, so you can modify it to better suit your needs. http://jsfiddle.net/7qB4G/6/

Comment: Serlite, call me a noob but it's still not working for me http://jsfiddle.net/bettyzyc/jVGzk/

Comment: Hmmm, not sure which part you mean is not working. Do you mean the title appearing? Because you'll need to add some more JavaScript/HTML for that. I've changed your CSS a little so the images don't stretch out of their aspect ratio when scaled, and I've included jQuery so the fadeOut() works: http://jsfiddle.net/jVGzk/3/

Comment: Thank you Serlite. You fixed up the % of width, changed height from  fixed to auto which means the height will automatically be in proportion, but it looks like that made all the images unmatch at the top and bottom.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, that's how the actual aspect ratios of the images are. If they aren't identical, I don't think you'll be able to get them to have the same height. You can remove `vertical-align:middle` if you want to align at least one edge; I just added that style so they would have equal spacing on both the top and the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

In my CSS solution, I divided the "container" class width by 3 (300px /3) and then subtracted 10px (which i got from padding-left and padding-right of each image). So a single image should have a width of 90px. However, I also wanted to subtract 5px more for browser spacing so the total width of each image should be 85px. Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
.container img {
    width: 85px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
   <img src="http://images2.webydo.com/31/313624/3958/21b785db-14ea-42f7-af0d-7e7a8d8019d9.jpg" />
   <img src="http://images2.webydo.com/31/313624/3958/9657ddfd-81e8-4154-bc61-bbe30e4a8740.jpg" />
   <img src="http://images2.webydo.com/31/313624/3958/909af36d-b941-4a20-9441-20505c035da3.jpg"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you add some text to explain how your solution works?

Comment: i divided the "container" class width by 3 (300px /3) and then subtracted

Comment: and then subtracted 10px(which i got from padding-left  and  padding-right of each image). so a single image should have a width of 90px.but i also wanted to subtract 5px more for browser spacing so the total width of each image should be 85px